# Get Average value for each X rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let`s say I have the following table

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   2.0 |
|  2 |   8.0 |
|  3 |   3.0 |
|  4 |   9.0 |
|  5 |   1.0 |
|  6 |   4.0 |
|  7 |   2.5 |
|  8 |   6.5 |
+----+-------+
```

I want to plot these values, but since my real table has thousands of values, I thought about getting and average for each X rows. Is there any way for me to do so for, ie, each 2 or 4 rows, like below:

```
2
+-----+------+
| 1-2 |  5.0 |
| 3-4 |  6.0 |
| 5-6 |  2.5 |
| 7-8 |  4.5 |
+-----+------+

4
+-----+------+
| 1-4 |  5.5 |
| 5-8 |  3.5 |
+-----+------+
```

Also, is there any way to make this X value dynamic, based on the total number of rows in my table? Something like, if I have 1000 rows, the average will be calculated based on each 200 rows (1000/5), but if I have 20, calculate it based on each 4 rows (20/5).

I know how to do that programmatically, but is there any way to do so using pure SQL?

EDIT: I need it to work on mysql.

Comment: What database--oracle, MySQL, what?

Comment: MySQL. Question updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS, something like this will work:

```
SELECT
   ChunkStart = Min(Id),
   ChunkEnd = Max(Id),
   Value = Avg(Value)
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         Chunk = NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY Id),
         *
      FROM
         YourTable
   ) AS T
GROUP BY
   Chunk
ORDER BY 
   ChunkStart;
```

This creates 5 groups or chunks no matter how many rows there are, as you requested.

If you have no windowing functions you can fake it:

```
SELECT
   ChunkStart = Min(Id),
   ChunkEnd = Max(Id),
   Value = Avg(Value)
FROM
   YourTable
GROUP BY
   (Id - 1) / (((SELECT Count(*) FROM YourTable) + 4) / 5)
;
```

I made some assumptions here such as `Id` beginning with 1 and there being no gaps, and that you would want the last group too small instead of too big if things didn't divide evenly. I also assumed integer division would result as in Ms SQL Server.

Comment: It worked flawlessly on sqlite3, but in mysql it didn't work as expected: [link](http://pastebin.com/rqwRg7ES). I forgot to mention I need it to work on mysql.

Comment: I managed to make it work changing the last line to `Floor((Id - 1) / Floor(((SELECT Count(*) FROM YourTable) + 4) / 5))`. Thank You!

Comment: the assumption of there being no gaps only applies to the 'fake it' version

Comment: for reference - NTILE: Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number of groups. The groups are numbered, starting at one. For each row, NTILE returns the number of the group to which the row belongs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Comment: it is important to add `ORDER BY ChunkStart` or the chunks will/may come out of order

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulos operator to act on every Nth row of the table.  This example would get the average value for every 10th row:

```
select avg(Value) from some_table where id % 10 = 0;
```

You could then do a count of the rows in the table, apply some factor to that, and use that value as a dynamic interval:

```
select avg(Value) from some_table where id % (select round(count(*)/1000) from some_table) = 0;
```

You'll need to figure out the best interval based on the actual number of rows you have in the table of course.

EDIT:
Rereading you post I realize this is getting an average of every Nth row, and not each sequential N rows.  I'm not sure if this would suffice, or if you specifically need sequential averages.

Comment: I need these value to draw a small line chart, so the values need to be sequential. Getting only the Nth values would let me create something already, but I am afraid of ignoring some values.

Comment: how to use it in a loop, i am able to get the avg of first 10 rows, but after that it repeats the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the NTILE function (as in quartile, quintile, decile, percentile). You can use it to split your data evenly into a number of buckets - in your case it seems you would like five.

Then you can use AVG to calculate an average for each bucket.

NTILE is in SQL-99 so most DBMSes should have it.

Comment: Sorry, but I need it to work on MySQL, which does not support NTILE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable
(
    ID int
    ,[Value] float
)
INSERT #YourTable (ID, [Value]) VALUES
 (1,2.0)
,(2,8.0)
,(3,3.0)
,(4,9.0)
,(5,1.0)
,(6,4.0)
,(7,2.5)
,(8,6.5)


SELECT
    ID = MIN(ID) + '-' + MAX(ID)
    ,[Value] = AVG([Value])
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        GRP = ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) -1) / 2) + 1
        ,ID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID)
        ,[Value]
    FROM
        #YourTable
) GrpTable
GROUP BY 
    GRP

DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Francois Morin! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update you solution with an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)