# how to read/decipher a user defined mathematical formula and perform requested operation in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user defined formula stored in mysql table as **AVG({Arrival_Date}-{Departure_Date})** I managed to get items Arrival_Date and Departure_Date then select the rows from a separate table.

How can I replace {Arrival_Date} and {Departure_Date} from **AVG({Arrival_Date}-{Departure_Date})** with the actual data selected from database table?

Comment: you want the DB to calculate this average, or php? Because if you're doing templates in SQL, good luck with ripping out whatever hair you've got left. SQL is not a language you want to be doing templating in.

Comment: I want to do in php. Thanks Marc

Comment: then `str_replace('{Arrival_Date}', $date_you_want, $str_from_db)`

Comment: Not sure this fits your needs exactly, yet it might put you in a good direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642329/get-average-value-for-each-x-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks all for your suggestion. I solved the above using https://github.com/jlawrence11/eos. So there is no need of trying to decipher the formula as long as it follows bodmas rule.

You only read the formula as defined, pass the values(numbers or floats) to the formula and then call eos to do the computation.

Example:

```
  <?php

      $formula_as_defined = AVG({Arrival_Date}-{Departure_Date})  ; //get the formula from database

      $str= str_ireplace('{','',$formula_as_defined);
      $mod_str= str_ireplace('}','',$str);
      $mod_str;
      //
 foreach($sql_select_resultset as $array) //This an array of values selected from db table #1 => Arrival_Date #2 =>Departure_Date
              {
                  foreach($array as $key => $value)
                  {
                      $col_mod[]= $key;

                      $val_mod[]= strtotime($value);
                      //
                  }
                    $char_mod = str_ireplace($col_mod,$val_mod,$mod_str);
                    unset($col_mod);
                    unset($val_mod);
                    //
                  //   $equation = "(".strtotime('13-07-2015')."-".strtotime('20-07-2015').")";
                     $equation = $char_mod  ;
                     $eq = new eqEOS();
                     $result = $eq->solveIF($equation); //pass the your formula to solveIF and your are done.
                     //
                     $myresults = $this->groupData($myresults,$array,$x_axis_column,$results_type_time);
                     array_push($myresults[date('m',strtotime($array[$x_axis_column]))],$result);

              }
     ?>
```