# How to get the average of every three records in a column starting from first record in MS Access/SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am working on something where i am stuck in getting the average of say every three/four/five records starting from first record in a column. If i have a table with data say

```
ID_Col1 | Value_Col2
1       | 1.5
2       | 2
3       | 2.5
4       | 3
5       | 3.5
6       | 4
7       | 4.5
8       | 5
9       | 5.5
10      | 6
```

If we say average of every three records then the Output required is

```
    every_three_records_average_Column
    none
    none
    average(1.5, 2, 2.5)
    average(2, 2.5, 3)
    average(2.5, 3, 3.5)
    average(3, 3.5, 4)
    average(3.5, 4, 4.5)
    average(4, 4.5, 5)
    average(4.5, 5, 5.5)
    average(5, 5.5, 6)
```

Does anyone have any idea to get this kind of output in SQL query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Honey

Comment: Access or MYSQL? Pick a card any card!

Comment: @RiggsFolly-MS-Access

Comment: I know it is MySQL but hopefully this can help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642329/get-average-value-for-each-x-rows-in-sql)

Comment: I am trying using SELECT (t1.Val + t2.Val + t3.Val)/3 AS Average_Value
FROM Tbl t1 
INNER JOIN Tbl t2 ON t1.ID-1=t2.ID
INNER JOIN Tbl t3 ON t2.ID-1=t3.ID

Comment: @honey What is the problem with that query? Is just what I did and works ok

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza- Thanks for your Answer. The query i mentioned above is giving me "Missing Operator - Syntax Error". Upto Two joins it works fine but when i try for three or more it's giving me this error. I'm trying this in SQL query written in MS-Access.

Comment: I've edited my answer, and added explanations. would you like to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/XAU37285)**

```
SELECT 
     T1.[ID_Col1], T2.[ID_Col1], T3.[ID_Col1],
     T1.[Value_Col2] , T2.[Value_Col2] , T3.[Value_Col2],
     (T1.[Value_Col2] + T2.[Value_Col2] + T3.[Value_Col2])/3

FROM Source T1
JOIN Source T2
  ON T1.[ID_Col1] = T2.[ID_Col1] - 1 
JOIN Source T3
  ON T2.[ID_Col1] = T3.[ID_Col1] - 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT Avg(A.Value_Col2) As Result
    FROM myTable As A
    WHERE A.ID_Col1 >= C.ID_Col1 and A.ID_Col1 < C.ID_Col1 + [MyParam]
)
FROM myTable As C
WHERE C.ID_Col1 + [MyParam] -1 <= (SELECT MAX (D.ID_Col1) From myTable As D)
```

**Explanation:**

- **External query:** *For each record in `mytable` `C`, until `MyParam`* (3, 4, or 5 in the question), *records befor the last record.*
  Represented in the query in the `where` clause: `FROM myTable As C WHERE C.ID_Col1 + [MyParam] -1 <= (SELECT MAX (D.ID_Col1) From myTable As D)`
- **Inner query:** *Calculate the average `Value_Col2` of `MyParam` records, starting the current record.*
  Representd in the `Select` statement: `SELECT Avg(A.Value_Col2)` and in the `Where` clause: `WHERE A.ID_Col1 >= C.ID_Col1`, as `C.ID_Col1` being the *current* ID, and and no more than `[MyParam]` records: `A.ID_Col1 < C.ID_Col1 + [MyParam]`.

**Test**

```
MyTable:
ID_Col1 Value_Col2
1       1.5
2       2
3       2.5
4       3
5       3.5
6       4
7       4.5
8       5
9       5.5
10      6
11      6.5
12      7
13      7.5
14      8
15      8.5
16      9
17      9.5
```

**Result for `MyParam` = 3**

```
Result
2
2.5
3
3.5
4
4.5
5
5.5
6
6.5
7
7.5
8
8.5
9
```

**Result for `MyParam` = 5**

```
Result
2.5
3
3.5
4
4.5
5
5.5
6
6.5
7
7.5
8
8.5
```

Comment: OK, I tested it, modified a bit, now it works just fine ;)

Comment: @honey - haven't you received fine answers to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a correlated aggregate subquery filtering on last three IDs:

```
SELECT myTable.ID_Col1, myTable.Value_Col2,

       (SELECT Avg(sub.Value_Col2)
        FROM myTable As sub
        WHERE sub.ID_Col1 >=  myTable.ID_Col1 - 2
        AND sub.ID_Col1 <=  myTable.ID_Col1
        AND myTable.ID_Col1 >= 3) As LastThreeAvg

FROM myTable;
```

Output

```
ID_Col1   Value_Col2  LastThreeAvg
1         1.5       
2         2     
3         2.5         2
4         3           2.5
5         3.5         3
6         4           3.5
7         4.5         4
8         5           4.5
9         5.5         5
10        6           5.5
```

However, if `ID_Col1` is an AutoNumber field, there is no guarantee values will remain in numeric ordinal count. Therefore, a calculated row number, `RowNo`, is needed in both the derived table and aggregate subquery. In MS Access SQL without CTEs, the query becomes a bit verbose:

```
SELECT dT.ID_Col1, dT.Value_Col2, 

       (SELECT Avg(sub.Value_Col2)
        FROM 
             (SELECT ID_Col1, Value_Col2,
                     (SELECT Count(*) 
                      FROM myTable As sub
                      WHERE sub.ID_Col1 <= myTable.ID_Col1) As RowNo
             FROM myTable) As sub
        WHERE sub.RowNo >=  dT.RowNo - 2
        AND sub.RowNo <=  dT.RowNo
        AND sub.RowNo >= 3) As LastThreeAvg
FROM

(SELECT ID_Col1, Value_Col2,
        (SELECT Count(*) 
         FROM myTable As sub
         WHERE sub.ID_Col1 <= myTable.ID_Col1) As RowNo
FROM myTable) As dT
```